# How to apply css styles to codeigniter dropdown?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone explain me how to apply css styles to form_dropdown function in codeigniter ? I would like the form to look like

```
<select name="dropdown" style="width: 240px; font-size: 13px">
....
</select
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from the fact it'd be best to define the styles via an external stylesheet rather than inline, you can do it as follows:

```
form_dropdown('dropdown', $options, $selected, 'style="width: 240px; font-size: 13px"');
```

You could just as easily add a class to the `<select>` and then add the styles in your stylesheet:

```
form_dropdown('dropdown', $options, $selected, 'class="foo"');
```

In either case, if you don't have a value for `$selected`, set it to `array()`

```
form_dropdown('dropdown', $options, array(), 'style="width: 240px; font-size: 13px"');
```

Although you could get away setting it to `null` or `''` for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

try this one I use **bootstap** class call **.form-control**

```
 <?php echo form_dropdown('Cuntry"'.'class="form-control', $Cuntry); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

form_dropdown('dropdown', $options, $selected, 'class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="8" ');

**data-size="8"**